# How to change the log level in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using this code to enable logging in my Sinatra app:

```
log_file = File.new('my_log_file.log', "a") 
$stdout.reopen(log_file)
$stderr.reopen(log_file)    
$stdout.sync=true
$stderr.sync=true
```

The actual logging is done using:

```
logger.debug("Starting call. Params = #{params.inspect}")
```

It turns out that only INFO or higher level log messages are logged and DEBUG messages are not logged. I am looking for a way to set up the log level to DEBUG.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess there might be a better way, but you can always do something like setting the log level in a `before` filter:

```
before do
  logger.level = 0
end
```

Comment: I was thinking of the same, but I am hoping there is a better way than this.

Comment: If you use rackup, I guess you can change your logger in your `.ru` file, as Sinatra's logger is in fact the one from Rack.

Comment: I havent been able to find a better solution, hence accepting this answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set this in a config block

Comment: @DaveSag: What about the other answer, it looks promising for your case?

Comment: Okay I adapted the answer by @david-faber and it works.  Will post below.

Answer (score 30):

You can set the log level using

```
configure :development do
  set :logging, Logger::DEBUG
end
```

Sinatra sets you up with Rack::Logger in its default middleware, which can be initialized with a log level (see http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Logger.html).  Sinatra initializes it with your `logging` setting, so you can put a number (or `Logger` constant) there instead of just `true`.

FYI, here is the relevant method from the `Sinatra::Base` source code that initializes the Rack::Logger middleware ([found here](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/311aa4264600b324978d36e01c82755bf17246e0/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1406))

```
def setup_custom_logger(builder)
  if logging.respond_to? :to_int
    builder.use Rack::Logger, logging
  else
    builder.use Rack::Logger
  end
end
```

This is on Sinatra 1.3.2, I don't know if it was different in earlier versions

Answer (score 6):

In my situation the only way I could get logging to work reliably was as follows: (simplified example)

Firstly I set up the logger and log folder as follows:

```
require 'logger'

configure do
  log_dir = "#{root}/log"
  Dir.mkdir(log_dir) unless Dir.exists?(log_dir)
  file = File.new("#{log_dir}/#{environment}.log", 'a+')
  file.sync = true
  use Rack::CommonLogger, file
end
```

Then in separate environment config

```
configure :test do
  set :logging, Logger::ERROR
end

configure :development do
  set :logging, Logger::DEBUG
end

configure :production do
  set :logging, Logger::INFO
end
```

This works a treat.