# Sinatra: Log noise when running rspec tests

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

New to Sinatra; I'm running some rspec tests but getting a bunch of unwanted noise in the logs.  How do I get rid of the excessive noise in the logs?  I've double checked that the environment is set to :test, which means logger level should be set to WARN instead of DEBUG.

**spec_helper:**

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra"
require "rspec"
require "rack/test"
require "database_cleaner"
require "factory_girl"

set :environment, :test

FactoryGirl.definition_file_paths = %w{./factories ./test/factories ./spec/factories}
FactoryGirl.find_definitions

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rack::Test::Methods
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # Use color in STDOUT
  config.color_enabled = true

  # Use color not only in STDOUT but also in pagers and files
  config.tty = true

  # Use the specified formatter
  config.formatter = :documentation # :progress, :html, :textmate

  config.order = "random"

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

def app
  Sinatra::Application
end
```

**app.rb**

```
configure :test do
  set :database, 'sqlite3:///test.sqlite'
  set :logging, Logger::ERROR
end
```

**noise:**

```
D, [2014-01-16T22:14:28.481790 #75797] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  commit transaction
D, [2014-01-16T22:14:28.484622 #75797] DEBUG -- :    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
```

Comment: According [the second answer on this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429326/change-log-level-in-sinatra), `Logger::ERROR` needs to respond to :to_int. Can you fire up a console and give that a try? If it doesn't respond to to_int, sinatra will use the default logging setting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regards to Ben's answer: I put this in my spec helper:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil unless ENV['LOG'] == true
```

There were some rare cases where I found that output useful, and including the conditional with environment variable made it super easy to turn logging on, while keeping it off by default.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the noise is coming from the ActiveRecord logger.
Setting `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = nil` in the spec helper gets rid of the SQL noise.